# При чтение письма с почты по IMAP ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, gmail, imap

Все письма читаются, но некоторые выдают ошибку

```
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\mail.py", line 121, in <module>
    if LastSubject != ReadingMail():
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\mail.py", line 50, in ReadingMail
    body = payload.get_payload(decode=True).decode('UTF-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Кусок кода

```
email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string, policy=policy.default)
        
    if email_message.is_multipart():
        for payload in email_message.get_payload():
            body = payload.get_payload(decode=True).decode('UTF-8')
            #print(body)
    else:    
        body = email_message.get_payload(decode=True).decode('UTF-8')
        #print(body)
```

Как исправить эту ошибку чтобы читались все письма и без ошибки?

Comment: А вы уверены, что там `utf-8`? Может там `cp1251` или `utf-16` (и их ещё и два варианта бывает).

Comment: Да, а без `.decode('UTF-8')` не пробовали, может оно вообще лишнее?